# MongoDB java driver using regex query to retrieve first two character

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

i want to retrieve first two character value like if i give 02-01-2017 00:05:46 i should get result like

```
02-01-2017 00:05:46 
02-01-2017 00:05:46 
02-01-2017 00:05:46
```

Without string SyTime_000_09_00:00

i am using jongo library and mongo drive 3.4.2

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("590b70c609200535e85c6540"),
  "Data" : "02-01-2017 00:05:46 SyTime_000_09_00:00 "
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("590b70c609200535e85c6541"),
  "Data" : "02-01-2017 00:05:46 DPMPow_P01_04_  45.53 "
}
```

Here is what i have tried

```
public class DataSource {
  private MongoCollection collection;

  public void DataSource() {
    this.collection = (new Jongo(new
        MongoClient("localhost", 27017).getDB("admin"))).getCollection("test");
  }

  public void guarder(Object obj) {
    this.collection.save(obj);
  }

  public Iterable consol() {
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("02-01-2017");
    query.put("Data", regex);
    return (Iterable) this.collection.find(query.toString()).as(pojo.class);
  }
}
```

here is pojo class

```
   public class pojo {
   @MongoObjectId 
   String _id;        
   String Data;


  public pojo() {

  }

   public pojo(String Data) {
    this.Data = Data;
   }


  public String getData() {
    return Data;
   }


   public String getId() {
    return _id;
   }
```

}

i am using jframe Button Action GUi

```
      private void findActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    try{

     DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
     DataSource ds=new DataSource(); 
     ds.DataSource();

        Iterable pojo=ds.consol();
        pojo p;
        int i=0;
        for (Iterator it=pojo.iterator();it.hasNext();){  
        p = (pojo)it.next();
         listModel.addElement(p.getData());

        }
      mdata.setModel(listModel); //jlist

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: Based on the example, you want to retrieve the string before the first space. Is this correct?

Comment: What if you use `Pattern.compile("02-01-2017 [0-9:]+");`? I guess this will return all *entries* with this match, and you need to get only the match, right?

Comment: i want to show result in my Jlist only "02-01-2017 00:05:46" without String   right now i am getting result in my table like this "02-01-2017 00:05:46 SyTime_000_09_00:00" you can also look at the result image,  i want to trim before it reaches to the Jlist. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: my query is  working accordingly as wanted, only the problem is i am getting result like this **"02-01-2017 00:05:46 DPMPow_P01_04_  45.53"** in my Jlist i want to get result  like this "02-01-2017 00:05:46" without String @TamasRev

Comment: Can't you post-process the results? Iterate over them and use `entry.replaceFirst("^(\\S+\\s\\S+).*", "$1")`

Comment: i have update the post now you can look at the process , where i can use this entry.replaceFirst("^(\\S+\\s\\S+).*", "$1"), i am sorry but i don't get it. @ WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Look, `p.getData()` returns a `String` that is added to the `listModel`. Use `p.getData().replaceFirst("^(\\S+\\s\\S+).*", "$1")`. Does it work like this?

Comment: you are hero bro thank you so much @ WiktorStribiżew

Comment: can you put this as an answer please @ WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Wiktor Stribiżew

> p.getData() returns a String that is added to the listModel. Use p.getData().replaceFirst("^(\S+\s\S+).*", "$1")